# How to add an active class for a Navbar?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm been struggling to add an "active" class for the navbar selection but I can't seem to get it right. I used jQuery here to add the class by following an example but I'm having a hard time implementing this. So When I press the link button for e.g. Home it should activate add the active class. The thing is it doesn't and no console errors found. It simply won't add the active class to the navbar links.

Here's what I have done.

My Navbar html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
            <img src="Assets/Images/spicy-food.svg" height="28" alt="SpiceFoods">
        </a>
        <h2 class="Nav-brand">Spice Foods</h2>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <a href="#" data-value="carouselIndicator" class="nav-item nav-link btn-ripple">Home</a>
                <a href="#" data-value="About" class="nav-item nav-link btn-ripple">About</a>
                <a href="#" data-value="Products" class="nav-item nav-link btn-ripple">Our Spices</a>
                <a href="#" data-value="Contact" class="nav-item nav-link btn-ripple">Contact Us</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Here's the css

```
.navbar-nav div>a.active {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Here's my jQuery

```
$('.navbar-nav a').on('click', function () {
        console.log("Click");
        $('.navbar-nav').find('a.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent('a').addClass('active');
    });
```

How do I achieve this. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please create a runnable snippet / [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the comments below to see what has been changed:

```js
$('.navbar-nav a').on('click', function() {
  $('.navbar-nav').find('a.active').removeClass('active');
  // you had  $(this).parent('a').addClass('active') - but there IS no "a" parent... you want the active class on the clicked element....
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
/* you had .navbar-nav div > a.active ... however, there's no div between the navbar and the a.... */
.navbar-nav .active {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky">
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
    <img src="Assets/Images/spicy-food.svg" height="28" alt="SpiceFoods">
  </a>
  <h2 class="Nav-brand">Spice Foods</h2>
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <a href="#" data-value="carouselIndicator" class="nav-item nav-link btn-ripple">Home</a>
      <a href="#" data-value="About" class="nav-item nav-link btn-ripple">About</a>
      <a href="#" data-value="Products" class="nav-item nav-link btn-ripple">Our Spices</a>
      <a href="#" data-value="Contact" class="nav-item nav-link btn-ripple">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks @cale_b. This answer works for me. Since I tried this answer I'll mark this one as correct and upvote other answers since those work too.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change just one line.

Replace this line

```
$(this).parent('a').addClass('active');
```

with

```
$(this).addClass('active');
```

Comment: @cale_b -  I know css is not changing anything means visually making no difference. But I mentioned only one thing about js only so that writer of question can check what is not adding active class to anchor tags. I thought he/she can guess himself/herself about visual change. If he/she not able to guess, then he/she may ask in comments section.